# Will a Virtual Box Installation have low Disk performance

Tags: installation, virtualbox, wubi, performance, disk

I understand that if you install Ubuntu on Windows using Wubi, there are disk performance issues since the entire system is mostly concentrated on a single file.

What about the case of a Virtual Box, will it have improved performance over just installing on Windows with Wubi, or underneath they are the same thing.

Comment: "that if you install on Windows" ... If you install *what* on Windows?

Comment: I meant to say, not to create a separate partition for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu running inside VirtualBox on Windows will not have a better performance than Ubuntu installed wihtout separate partition (thus using file on Windows file system). Most likely the performance will be worse.

In the first case, you have a file on Windows FS + virtual machine; In the second case, you still have a file on Windows FS but no virtual machine.